# The import org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved : Java

Tags: automated-testing, java, exception

I am trying to do the following import in java project:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

This displays following **error message** in eclipse:

```
The import org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved
```

Kindly guide me on this error.

Comment: Are you using any dependency control like Maven? And when does that error happen? When you execute your code from IDE? or from CMD? if from IDE, which IDE are you using?

Comment: Not using Maven, i am using eclipse to run the code written in java after importing selenium.jar file into the project.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use Maven since I think "apache commons io" is not the only library you're missing. You would not see any import problems but when you run your code there would be ClassNotFound exception because a lot of libraries also depend on some other libraries, and you will have find, download and attach the corresponding jars to your project.

Comment: I suppose you are right, i opened the website - https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi following your words and i am not sure about how to proceed with installation and maven usage ...

Comment: i have installed maven successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the download the `"org.apache.commons.io.jar"` jar file. After that you have to add this downloaded jar in project lib and import it in class, it will work.

Comment: Following your advice, I went over to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi.Here i found src and bin zip files.After downloading these files i am struck about how to link these to my active eclipse project as i couldn't find a jar file. Appreciate your help ...

Comment: @Sudeept kindly refere this link http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44  for importing the external jar.