# import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Tags: java

I have the same issue I can not access "import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;" I get the message "The package org.apache.commons.io is not accessible", Although I have added the jar file but still not working, maybe i am not able to import. please give some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to discern what you are asking, it appears like you are trying to reply to another thread however instead this is an entirely new post. However, after some digging I found this may help you:

> You need the download the "org.apache.commons.io.jar" jar file. After that you have to add this downloaded jar in project lib and import it in class, it will work.

This answer can be found [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/33230/57205)